# How to let only certain people test interal itunes connect testing

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

So this seems rather dumb I have to ask seeing as it's all over the itunes connect page. But my question is rather simple. I want to release a test flight version out but only allow certain people access to it. We need to test things on our dev server but don't want ALL of our testers using the dev server (they would get confused). When I go to Test Flight --> iOS --> (click on version) --> There's a `Groups` tab. And it lists the groups for this build to test on... okay. That's fine. Except there's no way to delete a group. I just want to submit a built to test flight and just allow certain people access to it. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Screenshot of what im talking about
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group for those specific users, and add their emails to the group. Make sure the group is selected in the left sidebar, by default it will show the list of users you just added...

[image: Users tab]

But above the list you can choose the builds tab. Tap that and you will see this...

[image: Build tab]

Tap the + sign and choose the build that you want to share with this group of users. If this is the first time you have shared this version of the app it may have to be approved for Beta testing by Apple.

Comment: I've tried to add them, but it doesn't give me the option. Do they have to NOT be in the default group?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not give you the option? You don't get the + button? The existing user shows greyed out?

Comment: @combonatorial I updated my question with a screenshot. I can't add any of these users to this group. there's no 'check mark' next to there name. ANy insights?

Comment: If I take them out of itunesconnect users group, i can add them. also didnt know this was external testing too.

Comment: If they are in the itunesconnect group they automatically get the build when you upload a new one, so it makes sense that you couldn't add them to another group.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. What if I only want to release a version to a select people without releasing to everyone? Isn't that the point of groups? Why can't someone be in 2 groups, lol? Sorry, that does not make sense in the slightest. And is not documented anywhere. They should allow me to add people from the itunesconnect first of all. Second of all, they should give me some verbiage that tells me WHY I can't add. I assumed it was like a bug or something.

Comment: I agree the UI could be better. A user can be in multiple groups... just not the iTunes group which is special. This special group has access to every build and members are auto-notified immediately on a new build being uploaded. So, if you are in this group you have access to everything, there is no point being in another group.